# using several xmlrpc commands on twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I have a simple client code using xmlrpclib.

```
try:
       Server.func1
       Server.func2
       .....
       Server.funcN
except:
    pass
```

, where Server - ServerProxy from xmlrpclib. How to do this on twisted ?
I see this example:

```
from twisted.web.xmlrpc import Proxy
from twisted.internet import reactor

def printValue(value):
    print repr(value)
    reactor.stop()

def printError(error):
    print 'error', error
    reactor.stop()

Server = Proxy('http://advogato.org/XMLRPC')
Server.callRemote('func1',).addCallbacks(printValue, printError)
reactor.run()
```

but how to add several nesting callRemote functions ?

Answer (score 1):

You have code in the sample you pasted which takes an action when an XML-RPC call completes.  `printValue` prints the result of a call and `printError` print an error which occurs during a call.

If you want to make another call after one finishes, then maybe instead of just printing something in `printValue`, you could issue another `Server.callRemote` there.